# Binding StaticResourse Key in uwp

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, binding, uwp

i am trying to refix the hamburger menu with some FontAwesome Icons, my way to do this is a ResourseDictionoary in my app. Now i want to bind the key`FontAwesomeUserString` for the glyph bellow . My property in the object is Icon with type `string`. In my list the Icon var of `x:DataType="local:MenuItem"` has the values from my resoursedictionary.

```
<FontIcon Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeFontFamily}" Glyph="{StaticResource FontAwesomeUserString}" Foreground="White" />
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
```

Please tell me if/how i can bind the ResourceKey property of StaticResourse.
Thank you

Comment: You need to post your resource code also.  You're doing it correctly here. Just remember {StaticResource} is different from {Binding} but for what you're doing this looks correct.

Comment: Hi @MichaelPuckettII . thanks for the answer. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/amoraitis/AuebUnofficial/blob/Dev/AuebUnofficial/Helpers/HandlingUI/FontAwesomeDictionary.xaml), i want the static resource to take all the values from the code [behind](https://github.com/amoraitis/AuebUnofficial/blob/Dev/AuebUnofficial/Navig.xaml.cs) and here is my code in [xaml](https://github.com/amoraitis/AuebUnofficial/blob/Dev/AuebUnofficial/Navig.xaml)

Comment: Thanks Anastasios.  However; Vincent below has answered the question just as I would have give or take so take a look at what he's saying there.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the values of a resource dictionary by replacing them through code like:

```
Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeUserString"] = "&glyphCode";
```

Do not forget that `StaticResource` are only read when the page is created.

Depending when you are updating your dictionary, it could be enough but if you want your application to properly update itself when you are changing something in the resource dictionary, you will have to use `ThemeResource`.

You can get more details about `ThemeResource` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension).

```
<FontIcon Grid.Column="0" 
    FontFamily="{ThemeResource FontAwesomeFontFamily}" 
    Glyph="{ThemeResource FontAwesomeUserString}" 
    Foreground="White" />
```

**Update**

If you are just trying to set the glyph/font family for all your items, a regular binding is enough:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate" x:DataType="local:MenuItem">
        <Grid Width="240" Height="48">
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <FontIcon Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="{x:Bind FontFamily}" Glyph="{x:Bind Icon}" Foreground="White" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

You just have to define the `FontFamily` and the `Icon` in your view mod.
el 
You can have a look at the hamburger menu from the UWP toolkit [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/controls/hamburgermenu)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i cannot see how i can implement this in an object [like this](http://prnt.sc/e2d5u1) for binding. I want it to take different values. Not only the 'FontAwesomeUserString' value.